Manipulating Eye Floaters Appearance
This is a follow up question on my previous one on eye floaters
I am trying to think of a way to effectively remove them from vision by artificially decreasing the eye's depth of field.
I am wondering if there is a way to use an optical element or an array thereof, such that if positioned in front of someone's eye will give the same effect as if the eye's aperture (i.e. the pupil) was increased. In other terms, some sort of complex eyeglasses that give the equivalent effect of the pupil being dilated, without it physically being dilated.
One effect for example would be a decreased depth of field which would blur away the eye floaters from sight.
I believe the naive answer is - no. But I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Also could elements that have something to do with phase manipulation help here?
